# Time to detect Wink on Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, detection, google-gdk, android-gesture

I want to increase the time that Google Glass needs to detect a Wink.

I need that the Wink gesture is longer than the natural wink.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could calibrate what you would want to regard as a wink gesture in Settings.